# How do I match spark log pattern in grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm actually working on parsing some logs data and tried to implement a grok parser for spark logs.

Actually, this is one output from spark logs:

```
14/04/14 18:51:52 INFO Client: Command for the ApplicationMaster: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server -Xmx640m -Djava.io.tmpdir=$PWD/tmp org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class SimpleApp --jar ./spark-example-1.0.0.jar --args 'yarn-standalone' --worker-memory 1024 --worker-cores 1 --num-workers 3 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
```

And this is the grok filter I tried before:

```
(?<logtime>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{WORD:srcclass}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:data}"
```

This does not work for me. Can someone help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The only issue you have is the double quote at the end of your grok pattern, if you remove it you'll be fine. Also you don't need the `%{SPACE}` patterns unless you want to capture those spaces.

This is what worked for me:

```
(?<logtime>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{WORD:srcclass}: %{GREEDYDATA:data}
```

It will produce this

```
{
  "logtime": [
    [
      "14/04/14 18:51:52"
    ]
  ],
  "level": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "srcclass": [
    [
      "Client"
    ]
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "Command for the ApplicationMaster: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server -Xmx640m -Djava.io.tmpdir=$PWD/tmp org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class SimpleApp --jar ./spark-example-1.0.0.jar --args 'yarn-standalone' --worker-memory 1024 --worker-cores 1 --num-workers 3 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr"
    ]
  ]
}
```